# Portal Framework for PHP

Tags: php, portal

We are trying to create a portal for several different applications but are required by the client to do it in PHP. We would have preferred to do it in Java which has the JSR-168 and JSR-286 portlet specifications as well as supporting Portal servers (JBoss Portal, Liferay, ... ) however they want to standardize and insist on PHP.

Is there some kind of portal framework available for PHP?

I understand that it is easy to hack together a Javascript-based front-end emulating something like iGoogle but wanted to check if one already exists specific to PHP.

Comment: Is it bad that when I read the question title, I immediately tried to figure out how one would go about interfacing with the GAME portal through php?

Comment: @Cyclone: that definitely sounds more fun. :)